# How do you spell the software development tool that sounds like "Fitness"?

Tags: agile

Agile processes proponent Bob Martin often mentions in podcasts a tool that sounds like "Fitness". It is hard to search for this tool if you don't know how it is spelled. How is it spelled?

Comment: This is an object lesson in the importance of choosing a product name that doesn't lend itself to misspellings. Just what I'd expect from a proponent of Ajyle and Skrumm.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Since [apronyms](http://apronyms.com/apronyms.html) are so modern, I actually prefer them misspelled so I can better google them.

Comment: @DaveBall: your comment is an object lesson in how almost all design choices have both costs and benefits.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a spelling website.

Answer (score 3):

FitNesse

or

The fully integrated standalone wiki, and acceptance testing framework.

http://fitnesse.org/